# Webservices error "unable to read data from the transport connection" occasionally/randomly and for no obvious reason

Tags: asmx, pocketpc

I've got a PocketPC device that is sending and receiving data over asmx web services. For the most part this works fine, but it will randomly fail with the error of "unable to read data from the transport connection." The issue is, there's no rhyme or reason to this. Sometimes it will go weeks without trouble, and other times it will happen once a week, or several times a week.

Reading about this error, I find it can be connection trouble or a packet with too much data or something like that, but in all of the cases I've found it seems like the error is happening consistently. My problem is that it happens fairly rarely; any idea what would cause this to happen intermittently?

Comment: Any sort of intermittent network problem, either in the network itself or in either the client or the server, could cause this problem. Can you determine whether there's been a change in operational status of your NIC in the PocketPC?

Comment: I'm betting I had the other article you read about having errors with too much data. I never did get that one figured out. @cost: I'd love to hear how to do some of this asmx web service stuff with the PocketPC. [Contact Info](http://www.jp2code.net/Contact) provided.